# push to array in async/await

Tags: typescript, async-await

push to array in async/await should update collection array, but nothing happens!
tried Promise.all but doesn't helps

```
class Store {
  $collection: Document[] = [];

  collection = async (): Promise<any> => {
    let dir = await readdir("docs");

    dir.forEach(async (file) => {
      let document = await this.readDoc(file);
      this.$collection.push(document); // <-- nothing happens!
    });

    return this.$collection;
  };

  readDoc = async (uuid: string): Promise<Document> => {
    let buffer = await readFile(`docs/${uuid}`, "utf-8");
    let data: {} = await JSON.parse(buffer);

    return { uuid, data };
  };

const store = new Store();

console.log(await store.collection()); // returns [] instead of [{"version": "1.0","extension": "json","path": "docs"}]
```

push to array not working as expected

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` does not respect `async`, so you aren't waiting for all the promises to resolve before returning the collection. You should probably use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or `Promise.allSettled` to wait for all the promises to resolve in parallel:

```
const dir = await readdir("docs");

this.$collection.push(
    ...(await Promise.all(
        dir.map((file) => this.readDoc(file))
    ))
);

return this.$collection;
```

Then we can push all of the results to the collection at once.